# How to redirect custom panel quick form to full form?

Tags: sugarcrm

How to skip quick create form when I click on create action button on my custom subpanel?

I want to redirect when I click on create button. It needs to be redirected to full form on custom subpanel.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do the changes in following files:

custom/Extension/modules/*/Ext/Layoutdefs/*.php &&
custom/Extension/modules/relationships/layoutdefs/*.php

For your desired module/subpanel, change this line:

```
'widget_class' => 'SubPanelTopCreateButton',
```

by

```
'widget_class' => 'SubPanelTopButtonQuickCreate',
```

Then make a quick repair&rebuild.